# USB stick with Clonezilla and SystemRescueCD ISO on two partitions

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, gparted

I am familiar with [GParted](https://gparted.org/) basics and can partition a USB stick and install [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) on the first partition. My difficulties arise when I try to install the [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) ISO using **dd** onto the same stick. SystemRescueCD ISO simply writes over the whole stick; I cannot write it to /dev/sda1 or /dev/sda2. After it is finished the whole capacity of the stick is an  [ISO9660](https://www.iso.org/standard/17505.html) file.

Would it be possible to reduce this file/partition and re-partition the rest of the capacity? Or is there another way to have both tools on a single USB stick?

Comment: There are tools like Multisystem for that specific purpose.

Comment: dd can't be used the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple LiveLinux distros on the same USB Flashdrive, including Clonezilla and SystemRescue, and do it more easily than shrinking the dd-generated partition.

[MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/) [MultiBootUSB tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/multiple-linux-one-usb/)  and [MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/) [MultiSystem tutorial](https://www.unixmen.com/create-multiboot-usb-ubuntu-using-multisystem/) are two menu-driven apps which function in Linux, allow you to start from scratch, and create a flashdrive with multiple LiveLinux distros.

They also create a menu which allows you to select which OS you want to use at boot-from-live time, which you would not get from just shrinking the dd-generated partition and adding another distro.

Comment: MultibootUSB kept booting into the Grub CLI instead of the Grub menu, this seems to be a common problem. But Multisystem works perfectly! Thanks very much for the tip.